# Windows 8 app WebView catch event target="_blank"

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, webview, windows-8.1

I would like to create a webview on a windows application. 
The problem is that I don't know how to catch an event when a window will open with IE. When a link has target="_blank", windows automatically open IE. I tried to make the application with C# and JS but the issue is the same.
On the JS part, I tried to add an event with 'newwindow' but it doesn't work 
For the C# part, I used webview on the XAML and for the HTML I used x-ms-window 
The problem with some link is that they have target="_blank" into their tag. 
Is their a solution to this problem ? Is their a way to catch those event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution will be (using jQuery):

```
$('a[target=_blank]').on('click',function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    window.external.notify($(this).prop('href'));
});
```

In Windows 8 you must add your page (host) to `AllowedScriptNotifyUris`

In Windows 8.1 you will probably need to have some other workaround to use `window.external.notify` as allowed hosts are embedded in app manifest and must be loaded by https

Answer (score 0):

Startign on Windows 10, you can use the `WebView.NewWindowRequested` event:

```
private void WebView1_NewWindowRequested(
    WebView sender,
    WebViewNewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    // Prevent the browser from being launched.
    args.Handled = true;

    // Open the Uri in the current window.
    sender.Source = args.Uri;
}
```